# Javascript Memoization in Browser Not Seeing Speed Up

Tags: javascript, memoization

I am attempting to memoize a function in javascript, to be run in browser, client side. Writing this function in R (the language I am most comfortable using). In R, I see significant benefits from using memoization (4 minutes run time to 0.02 seconds for P_n(7/10, 20, 15, 6, 1) ). When I rewrite the function in javascript, I see almost no benefit.  What is the problem with my javascript code (or am I going about this the wrong way entirely)?

Below are the memoized functions in R and javascript respectively. The R function (first of the two) runs very fast compared to the naive recursion, while javascript essentially sees no difference. Some amount of memoization is happening, however, because if I run the exact same function call twice, i.e. P_memo(7/10, 20, 15, 6, 1) and then P_memo(7/10, 20, 15, 6, 1) again, the second call takes 0 time. The first call should be dramatically quicker due to re-use of intermediate calls in the recursion.

```
P_n <- (function() {

  # Memoization handled through the use of cache

  cache <- NULL

  cache_reset <- function() {
    cache <<- new.env(TRUE, emptyenv())
  }

  cache_set <- function(key, value) {
    assign(key, value, envir = cache)
  }

  cache_get <- function(key) {
    get(key, envir = cache, inherits = FALSE)
  }

  cache_has_key <- function(key) {
    exists(key, envir = cache, inherits = FALSE)
  }

  # Initialize the cache
  cache_reset()


  # This is the function that gets returned by the anonymous function and
  # becomes P_n
  function(rho, n, i, k, s) {
    nc <- paste(rho, n, i, k, s)

    # Handle "vectors" by element
    if(length(n) > 1){
      return(lapply(n, function(n) sapply(n, P_n, rho = rho, i = 1:(n+k), k = k, s = s)))  
    }
    if (length(i) > 1) {
      return(sapply(i, P_n, rho = rho, n = n, k = k, s = s))
    }

    # Cached cases
    if (cache_has_key(nc)) 
      return(cache_get(nc))


    # Everything else

    #proposition 1
    if(i == (n+k)){
      #print('Proposition 1')
      if(k >= s){
        return((rho / (rho + 1))^n)
      }else if( (k+n) <= s){
        product_iter = 1
        for(j in 1:n){
          product_iter = product_iter * ( rho + (k + j - 1)/s )
        }
        out = rho^n / product_iter
        cache_set(nc, out)
        return(out)
      }else if( k < s & s < (k + n)){
        product_iter2 = 1
        for(j in 1:(s-k)){
          product_iter2 = product_iter2 * ( rho + (k + j - 1)/s )
        }
        product_denom = ((rho + 1)^(n-s+k)) * product_iter2
        out = rho^n / product_denom
        cache_set(nc, out)
        return(out)
      }
    }
    #proposition 2
    else if(k == 0 & n == i){
      #print('Proposition 2')
      if(n <= s){
        product_iter11 = 1
        for(j in 1:n){
          product_iter11 = product_iter11 * (rho + (j - 1)/s)
        }
        return(rho^n / product_iter11)
      }else if(n > s){
        product_iter12 = 1
        for(j in 1:s){
          product_iter12 = product_iter12 * ( rho + (j - 1)/s )
        }
        product_denom12 = ((rho + 1)^(n-s)) * product_iter12
        out = rho^n / product_denom12
        cache_set(nc, out)
        return(out)
      }
    }
    #if i = 1
    else if(i == 1){
      upsum = 0
      for(j in 2:(n + k)){
        upsum = upsum + P_n(rho, n, j, k, s)
      }
      out = 1 - upsum
      cache_set(nc, out)
      return(out)
    }
    #proposition 3
    else if(n == 1 & 2 <= i & i <= k){
      #print('Proposition 3')
      if(k <= s){
        begin = rho / (rho + (i - 1)/s)

        product_iter13 = 1
        for(j in 1:(k-i+1)){
          product_iter13 = product_iter13 * (1 - rho / (rho + (k - j + 1)/s) )
        }
        out = begin * product_iter13
        cache_set(nc, out)
        return(out)
      }else if(k > s & i > s){
        out = rho / (rho+1)^(k-i+2)
        cache_set(nc, out)
        return(out)
      }else if(i <= s & s <= k){

        begin2 = rho / (( rho + 1 )^(k - s + 1) * ( rho + (i - 1)/s))

        product_iter14 = 1
        for(j in 1:(s-i)){
          product_iter14 = product_iter14 * (1 - rho / (rho + (s - j)/s) )
        }
        out = begin2 * product_iter14
        cache_set(nc, out)
        return(out)
      }

    }
    #proposition 4
    else if( n >= 2 & 2 <= i & i <= (k + n - 1)){
      #print('Proposition 4')
      if(i>s){
        begin11 = rho/(rho+1)

        product_iter21 = 0
        for(j in (i-1):(k+n-1)){
          product_iter21 = product_iter21 + (1 / (rho+1))^(j-i+1) * P_n(rho, n-1, j, k, s)
        }
        out = begin11 * product_iter21
        cache_set(nc, out)
        return(out)
      }else if(i <= s){

        begin12 = rho / (rho + (i-1)/s)
        summer1 = 0
        for(j in (i-1):(s-1)){

          product_iter22 = 1
          for(h in 1:(j-i+1)){
            product_iter22 = product_iter22 * (1 - rho / (rho + (j - h + 1) / s))
          }
          summer1 = summer1 + product_iter22 * P_n(rho, n-1, j, k, s)
        }

        product_iter23 = 1
        for(h in 1:(s-i)){
          product_iter23 = product_iter23 * (1 - rho / (rho + (s-h) / s))
        }

        summer2 = 0
        for(j in s:(k+n-1)){
          summer2 = summer2 + ((1 / (rho + 1))^(j-s+1) * P_n(rho, n-1, j, k, s)) 
        }

        bottom = product_iter23 * summer2
        inner = summer1 + bottom
        out = begin12 * inner
        cache_set(nc, out)
        return(out)
      }
    }
    #check if missed all propositions
    else{
      stop("No proposition detected")
    }

  }

})()
```

```
var P_memo = (function() {
    var memo = {};
    var slice = Array.prototype.slice;

    function f(rho, n, i, k, s){
        var args = slice.call(arguments);
        var value;
        if (args in memo) {
            return(memo[args]);
        }else{
            // NOTES ON THE UNITS OF INPUTS
            //rho: ratio of lambda / tau
            // n: arrival of nth customer
            // i: are i customers in queue
            // k : number of customers at t = 0
            // s: machines in use

            //proposition 1
            if(i == (n+k)){
                //print('Proposition 1')
                if(k >= s){
                    return(Math.pow(rho / (rho + 1), n));
                }else if( (k+n) <= s){
                    var product_iter = 1;
                    for(var j=1; j<= n; j++){
                        product_iter = product_iter * ( rho + (k + j - 1)/s );
                    }
                    return(Math.pow(rho, n) / product_iter);
                }else if( k < s && s < (k + n)){
                    var product_iter2 = 1;
                    for(var j=1; j<= s-k; j++){
                        product_iter2 = product_iter2 * ( rho + (k + j - 1)/s );
                    }
                    product_denom = Math.pow((rho + 1), (n-s+k)) * product_iter2;
                    return(Math.pow(rho, n) / product_denom);
                }
            }
            //proposition 2
            else if(k == 0 && n == i){
                if(n <= s){
                    var product_iter11 = 1;
                    for(var j=1; j<= n; j++){
                        product_iter11 = product_iter11 * (rho + (j - 1)/s);
                    }
                    return(Math.pow(rho, n) / product_iter11);
                }else if(n > s){
                    var product_iter12 = 1;
                    for(var j=1; j<= s; j++){
                        product_iter12 = product_iter12 * ( rho + (j - 1)/s );
                    }
                    product_denom12 = Math.pow((rho + 1), (n-s)) * product_iter12;
                    return(Math.pow(rho, n) / product_denom12);
                }
            }
            //if i = 1
            else if(i == 1){
                var upsum = 0;
                for(var j=2; j<= (n+k); j++){
                    upsum = upsum + f(rho, n, j, k, s);
                }
                return(1 - upsum);
            }
            //proposition 3
            else if(n == 1 && 2 <= i && i <= k){
                if(k <= s){
                    begin = rho / (rho + (i - 1)/s);

                    var product_iter13 = 1;
                    for(var j=1; j<= (k-i+1); j++){
                        product_iter13 = product_iter13 * (1 - rho / (rho + (k - j + 1)/s) );
                    }
                    return(begin * product_iter13);
                }else if(k > s && i > s){
                    return(rho / Math.pow((rho+1), (k-i+2)));
                }else if(i <= s && s <= k){

                    begin2 = rho / (Math.pow( (rho + 1), (k - s + 1)) * ( rho + (i - 1)/s));

                    var product_iter14 = 1;
                    for(var j=1; j<= (s-i); j++){
                        product_iter14 = product_iter14 * (1 - rho / (rho + (s - j)/s) );
                    }
                    return(begin2 * product_iter14);
                }

            }
            //proposition 4
            else if( n >= 2 && 2 <= i && i <= (k + n - 1)){
                if(i>s){
                    begin11 = rho/(rho+1);

                    var product_iter21 = 0;
                    for(var j=(i-1); j<= (k+n-1); j++){
                        product_iter21 = product_iter21 + Math.pow((1 / (rho+1)),(j-i+1)) * f(rho, n-1, j, k, s);
                    }
                    return(begin11 * product_iter21);
                }else if(i <= s){

                    begin12 = rho / (rho + (i-1)/s);
                    var summer1 = 0;
                    for(var j=(i-1); j<= (s-1); j++){

                        var product_iter22 = 1;
                        for(var h=1; h<=(j-1+1); h++){
                            product_iter22 = product_iter22 * (1 - rho / (rho + (j - h + 1) / s));
                        }
                        summer1 = summer1 + product_iter22 * f(rho, n-1, j, k, s);
                    }

                    var product_iter23 = 1;
                    for(var h=1; h<=(s-i); h++){
                        product_iter23 = product_iter23 * (1 - rho / (rho + (s-h) / s));
                    }

                    var summer2 = 0;
                    for(var j=s; j<= (k+n-1); j++){
                        summer2 = summer2 + (Math.pow((1 / (rho + 1)), (j-s+1)) * f(rho, n-1, j, k, s)) ;
                    }

                    bottom = product_iter23 * summer2;
                    inner = summer1 + bottom;
                    return(begin12 * inner);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    //Closure of f(), self-executing anonymous function
    return f;
})();
```

Comment: I don't see you actually *memoise* anything. Your code fetches from `memo` but never writes to it.

Comment: @VLAZ you're completely correct, huge brainfart on my part

Comment: Literally just adding memo[args] = whatever I was returning did it. Took me longer to make an account than it did to make the fix. Thank you for your quick answer and being patient with me

Answer (score 1):

Your memoization has two flaws:

(1) You never add results to `memo`.

(2) `args in memo`  casts `args` to a string. That will work for an array of numbers, but it might fail for other inputs.

I'd write a generic version of `memo` like this:

```
  const memo = fn => {
    const cache = {};
    return (...args) => {
      const key = JSON.stringify(args);
      if(key in memo) return memo[key];
      return memo[key] = fn(...args);
    };
  };

  const memoizedF = memo(f);
```